# Get record from last week weekday

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table contains temperature record of a machine every second as below. And I want to get the minimum and max value of each column (CH1~CH20) from last week's weekday. Is it possible to do it? I'm now stuck on how to select record from last week weekday.

[image: My Table]

Comment: This isn't a database table. It's a spreadsheet.

Comment: @Strawberry I took the snapshot from phpmyadmin, and why it is not a database table?

Comment: Because it's not normalised.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT MAX(CH1) FROM table where date < '2017-07-15' AND date > 2017-07-16';`

For minimum use MIN instead of MAX.
This could help you for each columns step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
SELECT MIN(CH1), MAX(CH1), MIN(CH2), MAX(CH2) FROM TABLE 
WHERE 
Date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 + WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY) 
AND
Date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 + WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY);
```